# How to make Raspberry Pi screen only take up a portion of the monitor

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I need to make the actual screen of my raspberry pi 4 only have a display width of 600 and height of 480 on a 800x480 px screen.

I have tried enabling overscan and setting left and right to 100 each, but that did not work. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Might want to try asking in [raspberrypi.se].

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding:

```
video=HDMI-A-1:800x480@60,margin_left=100,margin_right=100,margin_top=0,margin_bottom=0
```

to `/boot/cmdline.txt`